# Can't Connect to the remote MYSQL server via 3306 port

Tags: mysql, linux

I have been spending over 6 hours trying to solve this problem. After installing mysql server, I obviously changed bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0. I also tried commenting it out. When I check open port status with Nmap, it shows like below:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000011s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
23/tcp   open  telnet
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

so the 3306 port is definitely open. However, when I try to connect the server from my other machine, it shows:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '49.247.XXX.XXX' (61)
```

so I check it with telnet and the result is:

```
telnet: connect to address 49.247.XXX.XXX: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

so I go back to that server machine an check the status again with netstat and the result is like below:

```
❯ sudo netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      769/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      994/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      994/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::23                   :::*                    LISTEN      3355/xinetd
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      4108/mysqld
```

I find the number 3306 so it must be open right? I even tried the "sudo ufw allow XXXX/tcp" command to make sure 3306 is open. However, I ran out of ideas as to what is missing. Does anyone have any idea what to look for or how to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Comment: I think I would run wireshark to see what is going on. Port being open means just, that TCP handshake passes. It does not need to mean, that you are allowed to connect.

Comment: Still won't work. I have tried this method before

Comment: Okay will try Wireshark now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also set the firewalld.

Install Firewalld and do the following:

```
 firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp \ --permanent
```

this will make sure 3306 is open and accepting.